Einstein's index notation for symmetric tensors
Writing the product
$$
\mathbf{T} = \mathbf{A}^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\eta}\mathbf{A}\tag1
$$
in Einstein index notation I get:
$$
T_{\mu\nu} = (A^\text{T})^{\alpha}_{\,\,\mu}\eta_{\alpha\beta}A^{\beta}_{\,\,\nu}=A_{\mu}^{\,\,\alpha}\eta_{\alpha\beta}A^{\beta}_{\,\,\nu}\tag2
$$
Assuming $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ is symmetric I can easily see that $\mathbf{T}$ is symmetric, since:
$$
\mathbf{T}^\text{T} = (\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\eta}\mathbf{A})^\text{T}=\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\eta}^\text{T}(\mathbf{A}^\text{T})^\text{T}=\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\boldsymbol{\eta}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{T}
$$
However I struggle to show this in index notation, because:
$$
T_{\nu\mu} = A_{\nu}^{\,\,\alpha}\eta_{\alpha\beta}A^{\beta}_{\,\,\mu}=A^{\beta}_{\,\,\mu}\eta_{\beta\alpha}A_{\nu}^{\,\,\alpha}=A^{\alpha}_{\,\,\mu}\eta_{\alpha\beta}A_{\nu}^{\,\,\beta}
$$
But this does not seem to be the same as $T_{\mu\nu}$. So how can I show in index notation that $T_{\mu\nu}=T_{\nu\mu}$? I'm sure I'm overlooking something very elementary but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

One can find the issue by writing the matrix products in regular matrix notation. To perform this multiplication, we can first multiply the matrices on the left hand side:
$$ \left(\mathbf{A}^{T}\boldsymbol{\eta}\right)_{ij} = \sum_k A^T_{ik}\eta_{kj} \tag{1}$$
On the other hand, we could also perform the right hand multiplication first:
$$ \left(\boldsymbol{\eta}\mathbf{A}\right)_{ij} = \sum_k \eta_{ik}A_{kj} \tag{2}$$
However if we take seriously (as we must$^{\star}$) that the first index stands for rows and the second for columns, we see there's an inconsistency in what you wrote because here:

$$
T_{\mu\nu} = (A^\text{T})^{\color{red}{\alpha}}_{\,\,\mu}\eta_{\color{red}{\alpha}\color{blue}\beta}A^{\color{blue}\beta}_{\,\,\nu}
$$

We see that the multiplication of the matrices corresponding to $(2)$, is of the right form because the blue indices contract as a "row-column" pair.
However the left hand side that should correspond to $(1)$ is clearly not correct: the contracted indices in red both correspond to row indices.
Therefore in order to be consistent we see that the above must be written as:
$$
T_{\mu\nu} = (A^\text{T})_{\mu}{}^{{\color{red}{\alpha}}}\eta_{\color{red}{\alpha}\color{blue}\beta}A^{\color{blue}\beta}_{\,\,\nu}
$$
The result will then follow quite simply, as you can verify.

$\small\star$  We "must", when we need to go from matrix notation to tensor notation like in this example. Otherwise, mistakes evidently will occur. In general however, it is important to stress that there's no need to think about tensors with two indices as matrices. 

Restoring the matrix transpose operators so that it is easier to see what is happening,
$$
\begin{align}
(T^T)_{\mu\nu}=(T_{\nu\mu})^T
\tag1&=[(A^T)_\nu^{\ \ \alpha}\eta_{\alpha\beta}A^\beta_{\ \ \mu}]^T\\
\tag2&=(A^\beta_{\ \ \mu})^T\eta_{\beta\alpha}A^\alpha_{\ \ \nu}\\
\tag3&=(A^T)_\mu^{\ \ \beta}\eta_{\beta\alpha}A^\alpha_{\ \ \nu}\\
\tag4&=(A^T)_\mu^{\ \ \alpha}\eta_{\alpha\beta}A^\beta_{\ \ \nu}\qquad\text{(rewriting dummy indices)}\\
\tag5&=T_{\mu\nu}
\end  {align}
$$
In the usual Einstein index notation, the horizontal and vertical placements of the indices are all meaningful, and so there is no need to showcase the transpose operator; we write
$$
\begin{align}
T_{\nu\mu}
\tag6&=A_\nu^\alpha\eta_{\alpha\beta}A^\beta_\mu\\
\tag7&=A^\beta_\mu\eta_{\beta\alpha}A^\alpha_\nu\qquad\text{(using symmetry of metric)}\\
\tag8&=A_\mu^\alpha\eta_{\alpha\beta}A^\beta_\nu\qquad\text{(rewriting dummy indices)}\\
\tag9&=T_{\mu\nu}
\end  {align}
$$
It is only upon the implementation of a tensor equation in terms of matrices, do we need to expand the horizontal placements, and in so doing, clarify which quantity is the transposed matrix and which is not.

Hint: The slanted index position for the transposed matrix in eq. (2) should horizontally be the other way around:
$$(A^T)_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}~:=~A^{\alpha}{}_{\mu}.\tag{i}$$
In particular, since the original matrix is slanted NW-SE, the transposed matrix is slanted SW-NE. The transposition moves the indices horizontally. Then OP's eq. (2) is modified to
$$T_{\mu\nu} ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~(A^T\eta A)_{\mu\nu} ~=~(A^T)_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}\eta_{\alpha\beta}A^{\beta}{}_{\nu}~\stackrel{(\rm i)}{=}~A^{\alpha}{}_{\mu} \eta_{\alpha\beta}A^{\beta}_{\,\,\nu}~\stackrel{\eta^T=\eta}{=}~(\mu\leftrightarrow\nu).\tag{ii}$$
See also e.g. this related Phys.SE post.

This cannot be. The original matrix is defined as $\boldsymbol A=A^\beta_{\ \ \nu}$ and so the transpose must be defined with the horizontal positions as given, though, of course, it comes down to conventions whether it is written as $(A^T)\mu^{\ \ \alpha}$ or $A\mu^{\ \ \alpha}$

Hi @naturallyInconsistent. I seem to disagree with your above comment. Consider to explain your notation in greater detail.

It is interesting that the great Qmechanic is asking meow to explain. When we are trying to express tensors in index notation, you already know that the vertical placement deals with contra- v.s. co-variance, and the horizontal placement deals with row v.s. column. The conveniences of index notation means that we usually don't write down whether a tensor is transposed or not, simply moving the indices willy-nilly, secure in the understanding that, when we actually want to express them as matrices, some combination of transposing will make effecting the tensor equation possible. See my answer~

I disagree with the above "This cannot be" comment.

Look, comparing between the OP's Equations (1) and (2) (which I know you were the one to add the numberings), the rightmost A is clearly defining that $\boldsymbol A=A^\beta_{\ \ \nu}$ and so it cannot be redefined the way you want it to be. Instead, it is that $(A^\alpha_{\ \ \mu})^T=(A^T)_\mu^{\ \ \alpha}$ for things to match up correctly.

I see your newest edits. Yes, the original matrix is slanted NW-SE and so the transposed matrix must be SW-NE; and therein lies the complaint I was raising. Your Equation (i) is in disagreement with the original definitions.
